# Regular expression to return text between ( ) parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need the inner content of parenthesis of `(5*6)` i.e. `5*6`

i tried using:

```
/\((.*)\)/g
```

But unable to get `5*6`. How can I do this?

Comment: I can't see any problem. See https://regex101.com/r/bN2rS0/1

Comment: `var text = '(5*6)';
alert(text.slice(1, -1));` assuming the format is always like that

Comment: hello, my result is math.eval(5*6).. so i just need 5*6

Comment: i have to do mathematics operation on it so i just need 5*6 to do this..

Comment: The regular expression is correct: `/\((.*)\)/g.exec("(5*6)")` returns `["(5*6)", "5*6"]`. First item is the complete match. The following items are the groups in the regular expression - [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following regular expression does the trick:

```
/\d*[*\-\+\\]\d*/g
```

You could verify this [here](http://regexr.com/3ds7g)

Comment: But that's not compulsory to * will exists always some times there can + or - also

Comment: This expression would also match `-35%` as `-35` or `plus\\minus 17°F` as `\\` - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression returns an array with the full match (including `(` and `)`) and the "inner" part (which you want to use). So with

```
"(5*6)".exec(/\((.*)\)/g)[1]
```

you get it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this trick to solve your problem.

```
\((.*)\)
```

you can check it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Comment: @Rahul:  This can solve your problem of having either '+' or '-' then '*'